# jquery - disabling 'hover' doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table using odd/even and hover features for rows. I want to disable **hover** when I select a row.

This is my code:

```css
.odd{
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.even {
    background: #ffffff;
}

th:hover, tr:hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```
<tr class="myClass ${(k % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
```

```js
$('.myClass').click(function() {

    $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
    //I also tried this:
    $(this).off('hover');
});
```

Comment: would you please add a fiddle? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: try just remove class like so: removeClass(odd or even)

Comment: CSS `:hover` and JavaScript `.hover()` are not equivalent.

Comment: add a specific class to selected row and exclude it from css `:hover` pseudo class: `th:hover, tr:not(.myClass2):hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}` And then e.g: `$('.myClass').click(function() {$(this).addClass('myClass2');});`

Comment: How about changing your hover from td/tr to a custom class ("unselected") so you can remove the unselected class when a row is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `:hover` and JavaScript `.hover()` are not equivalent.

To resolve this issue I would likely go with adding or removing classes on click in JS and making my CSS more specific:

### CSS

```
th:not(.clicked):hover,
tr:not(.clicked):hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

What we're doing here is adding and removing the class `.clicked` on each click of the relevant element. Our CSS is then targeted to exclude elements with this class.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting confused with jQuery and CSS. You are applying the `hover` in CSS, not jQuery, so disabling the jQuery event for Hover will not stop the effect from occuring.

There is no way to disable the CSS hover event that I know of, you could try the following as a work around :

**CSS** : 
Add a custom class called `hover` to the CSS and apply the hover event to this.

```
.odd{
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.even {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.hover:hover {
    background: #e6e6e6;
}
```

**HTML** :

Add the new `hover` class to your initial HTML

```
<tr class="myClass hover ${(k % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
```

**jQuery** :

Remove the class when the item is clicked.

```
$('.myClass').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```